# Create multiple routes base on node(trip) in my XML file

Tags: jquery, xml, leaflet

Using Jquery I am initializing the code, which reads my XML file.

My problem is that its reading all my node(point) in one long leaflet route, and i want to split it up into two routes because i have two trips in my XML file.

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var waypoints = [];

$(xml).find("Trip").each(function () {
  $(xml).find("point").each(function () {

    var lat = $(this).find("lat").text();
    var lng = $(this).find("long").text();

    waypoints.push(L.latLng(lat, lng));

    L.Routing.control({
      plan: L.Routing.plan(waypoints, {
        geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
        draggableWaypoints: false
      }),
      addWaypoints: false,
      useZoomParameter: false,
      lineOptions: {
        styles: [{ color: "lightgreen", opacity: 1, weight: 5 }]
      }
    }).addTo(map)
  });
});


L.Routing.errorControl(control).addTo(map);
```

MY XML with route destinations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<destinations>
  <Trip>
    <LineColor>blue</LineColor>
   <point DriverNumber="11" name="Trip 1 start">    
      <lat>56.260919</lat>
      <long>10.057587</long>
      <type>Start</type>   
  </point>    
  <point DriverNumber="11" name="Trip 1 Destination">
    <lat>56.269234</lat>
    <long>10.00925</long>
    <type>Destination</type>
  </point>
</Trip>

  <Trip>
    <LineColor>blue</LineColor>
    <point DriverNumber="22" name="Trip 2 Sabro">
      <lat>56.211349</lat>
      <long>10.022631</long>
      <type>Start</type>
    </point>
    <point DriverNumber="22" name="Trip 2 Lyngballevej">
      <lat>56.222799</lat>
      <long>9.957336</long>
      <type>Start</type>
    </point>
    <point DriverNumber="22" name="Trip 2 Anbæk">
      <lat>56.234538</lat>
      <long>9.859930</long>
      <type>Destination</type>
    </point>
  </Trip>
</destinations>
```